# How are the waiting times distributed, poisson process.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I am wondering how the waiting times are distributed for the poisson process, conditioned on a number of events by time t. Look at this theorem:

[image: pic]

Here, the S's are the sum of the waiting time to event n. But I am interested in the $T_i's$. I know that unconditionally these are exponentially distributed, but what will the conditional distribution be? I tried to calculate these but I got $\frac{n!}{t^n}$ in this case also(the joint distribution of the T's), but this can't be?, since the S's and T's obviously can't have the same distribution?

Answer (score 1):

The conditional distribution of $(S_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ is uniform, that is, its density is
$$n!\,t^{-n}\,\mathbf 1_D,$$ where
$$
D=\{(s_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}\mid 0\leqslant s_1\leqslant\cdots\leqslant s_n\leqslant t\}.
$$
One is interested in the conditional distribution of $(T_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ where $T_1=S_1$ and $T_{k+1}=S_{k+1}-S_k$ for every $k\geqslant1$. A change of variable does the job.

To wit, if $t_1=s_1$ and $t_{k+1}=s_{k+1}-s_k$ for every $k\geqslant1$, then the domain $D$ becomes
$$
\Delta=\{(t_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}\mid \forall k,\,t_k\geqslant0,\ t_1+\cdots+t_n\leqslant t\},
$$ 
and the Jacobian is $1$, hence the conditional distribution of $(T_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ is uniform, that is, its density is
$$n!\,t^{-n}\,\mathbf 1_\Delta.$$

Comment: Thanks, so you agree that the S's and the T's basically have the same distribution? But I see they are not defined over the same area, so we can't say that they are exactly the same? Also could you please explain what you did with the change of variable and the jacobian how that was calculated? I have only seen change of variables in probability for X,Y to U(X,Y), v(X,Y), not in more dimensions.

Comment: I agree that the S's and the T's have completely different distributions.

Comment: Yeah I understand, what I meant was the the algebraic expression was the same, but the area where they are defined is not. But is there a book where it is explained this change of variable that you did? WHen I am in two dimensions I find it hard to find the new area when I change the variables, and I expect that in multiple dimensions it can be even harder. Is this explained in any book you know?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables

Comment: Thanks, but I did not see how to find the image in those links. I mean I see not that the condition $0 \le t_1..+t_n \le t$, must hold. But if it was not a so intuitive new image, how do we transform the D to the $\Delta$ image? Did yousubstitute every s in the inequality describing D, and solve for the t's?